# Изменение параметра JSON

Tags: python, json

Недавно начал учиться писать на python. Столкнулся с проблемой: мой код добавляет еще один параметр, а не изменяет его. Что мне делать?

**Код:**

```
def edit_json(path, chapter, text):
  if os.path.exists(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
      json_data = json.load(f)
      json_data[chapter] = text

    with open(path, 'w') as f:
      f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    sendLogText = 'Пользователь изменил в базе данных: \n"' + chapter + '":"' + text + '"'
    sendLogInfo(id, sendLogText, admin)
  else:
    print("Error.")
```

Прошу заметить, что sendLogInfo - это просто функция отправки лога, а path, chapter, text - передаются мной.

Ниже приведены фотографии JSON. Жду ответа. Спасибо.

**До этой функции:**

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "status": "",
        "action": "registration_tier_1",
        "isReg": "false"
    }
}
```

**После неё:**

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "status": "",
        "action": "registration_tier_1",
        "isReg": "false"
    },
    "action": "sendBotName",
}
```

Comment: `json_data["user"][chapter] = text`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для доступа к полю "action", вам необходимо обратиться к "user", а затем к "action".
Однако вы обращаетесь напрямую к "action" без "user", по этой причине создается новое поле, а не редактируется старое

```
json_data["user"][chapter] = text
```